# Django static media not showing picture

Tags: python, django

after searching for a solution for hours which did not resolve my problem,I am posting this. The image from my media root is not showing up on my html. In chrome's console i get a `404 file not found`.Even though the image is there. I am using Python 3 ,Django 1.10 in Pycharm.

This is the **model** which is where i upload images to:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    username = "anonymous"
    post = models.ImageField(upload_to='anon')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return Post.username
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def home(request):
    return render(request,"base.html",{})

def post_detail(request,id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    context = {
        "post": instance.post,
        "instance": instance
    }
    return render(request,"post_detail.html",context)
```

**post_detail.html**(here the image isnt showing):

```
<body>
    <img src = "{{ instance.post.url}}" height="520" width="500"><br>
    {{ instance.creation_date }}<br>
    {{ instance.username }}<br>
</body>
```

Parts of **setting.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Post',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Post.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Post.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Post/media/')
```

What my directories look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common mistake to mix up the static and media settings. In your case what you are actually dealing with is user uploaded MEDIA and not STATICs.

```
 <img src = "{{ instance.post.url}}" height="520" width="500"><br>
```

The settings that are most relevent are MEDIA_* settings described here 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

But more importantly, in your dev sever you need to enable the delivery of MEDIA by adding

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you so much,it worked after changing url from static to MEDIA_ROOT like you've stated.

Comment: glad to have helped