# Django: trouble serving media files

Tags: python, django

I have been through the Django documentation multiple times and multiple stackoverflow questions but I can't get media serving to work at all . No errors but just errors when getting the files.

Any help or extra sources to help me understand how to serve media files.

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT=BASE_DIR + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/media/')
MEDIA_URL='media/'
```

I have a usual folder structure :

```
/store { static, media, migrations,templates,  etc }
/venv
/staticfiles
manage.py
Procfiles
README
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
```

My requirements.txt

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.10.5
gunicorn==19.6.0
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==4.0.0
psycopg2==2.7
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

Model with image field:
class Product(models.Model):

```
product_category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
product_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
small_price = models.IntegerField()
medium_price = models.IntegerField()
large_price = models.IntegerField()
rating = models.FloatField()
image = models.ImageField( default='static/imgs/products/Cleanser.png')
```

Template code calling media :

```
 {% for product in all_products %}

    <div class="item  col-xl-4 col-lg-4" style="max-width: 400px;border-color:black;" >
        <div class="thumbnail" style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px grey;">

                    {% load staticfiles %}
                   <img class="group list-group-image" style="height:200px;width:120px;" src="{{ product.image   }}">



            <div class="caption" style="text-align:Center;">

                <p class="group inner list-group-item-heading"  style="font-family:Raleway;font-size:23px;color:black;">
                    <strong>{{ product.product_name}}</strong></p>

                <p class="group inner list-group-item-text" style="font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-style:italic;color:#222;opacity: 0.5">
                    {{ product.product_description }}</p>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 ">


                           <div class="form-group" >


                                <label for="size">Sizes</label>
                                <select class="form-control" class="size" style="max-width: 50%;margin:auto;">

                                  {% if product.product_category == "Milkshakes" %}
                                    <option value="{{product.medium_price}}" > Medium</option>

                                    {% else %}

                                  <option value="{{product.small_price}}" > Small ( 285ml )</option>
                                  <option value="{{product.medium_price}}" >Medium ( 350ml ) </option>
                                  <option value="{{product.large_price}}">Large ( 500ml )</option>
                                  {%endif%}

                                </select>



                                <input type="hidden" value="{{product.product_id}}" class='hidden'>




                                  <p style="margin-top:15px;"> <strong>Quantity &nbsp; </strong> </p>
                                  <button  type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-circle less" >-</button>
                                  <input  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle quantity" value=1></input>
                                  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle more" >+</button>
                                  <p> </p>
                                {% if discount != 0 %}
                                <p style="font-family: Raleway;color:black;font-size: 20px"> Discount &nbsp; <span style="color:rebeccapurple;opacity: 0.5">{{ discount }}%</span></p>
                                {% endif %}
                                <p class="sizer" style="color:black" >MUR &nbsp;</p> <p class="price" style="color:rebeccapurple;opacity: 0.8">{{ product.small_price }}</p>

                                <p> </p>

<button type="input" class="btn btn-success buy"  style="border-
color:#8A2BE2;background-color: #8A2BE2;margin-top:-20px;font-
size:17px;font-family: Raleway"> Add  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" 
aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                                    </div>



                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    {% endfor%}
```

Edit:

URLs.py addition for media seriving :

```
 from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static,staticfiles_urlpatterns

  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()        urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
 -urlpatterns += static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)         +urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Put a `print(MEDIA_ROOT)` after `MEDIA_ROOT=BASE_DIR + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/media/')`. What do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django static media not showing picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660546/django-static-media-not-showing-picture)

Comment: @nik_m it actually prints blank (heroku deployment)

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT` should be nearly identical to `STATIC_ROOT` unless you have some unique case. Why are you adding `BASE_DIR` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/media/')`? Try doing what you do for `STATIC_ROOT: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/media/')`

Comment: You cannot store user uploaded media files in the Heroku system. You must use an external storage like S3.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it doesn't work locally as well. However thank you for that insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had to modify my main urls.py to serve media files:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^homepage/', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^login/', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/', include('register.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # For serving media files on development server
```